# Initial setup of terraform backend using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I'm just getting started with terraform and I'd like to be able to use AWS S3 as my backend for storing the state of my projects.

```hcl
terraform {
    backend "s3" {
      bucket = "tfstate"
      key = "app-state"
      region = "us-east-1"
    }
}
```

I feel like it is sensible to setup my S3 bucket, IAM groups and polices for the backend storage infrastructure with terraform as well.

If I setup my backend state before I apply my initial terraform infrastructure, it reasonably complains that the backend bucket is not yet created. So, my question becomes, how do I setup my terraform backend with terraform, while keeping my state for the backend tracked by terraform. Seems like a nested dolls problem.

I have some thoughts about how to script around this, for example, checking to see if the bucket exists or some state has been set, then bootstrapping terraform and finally copying the terraform tfstate up to s3 from the local file system after the first run. But before going down this laborious path, I thought I'd make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: This is a good question. FWIW we had a separate "bootstrap" TF project, which in turn relied on a super-minimal manually provisioned bucket.

Comment: Yeah I've done something similar where a bootstrap project copies across a bunch of helper scripts and provider configs for a project and also creates a versioned S3 bucket and DynamoDb lock table if it doesn't exist using the AWS CLI. It would be nice if we could do that in Terraform but when I tried it was too messy to be worth it.

Comment: Terragrunt also can take care of this for you, and makes it really convenient if you want to move to a different bucket.
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt

Comment: Is there a better way to do this in 2020 ? I have seen suggestions of using a local state for the s3 creation in a different folder. I don't think that's the right approach for a CD plan. Have anyone found a better way ?

Comment: I used the same solution that you suggested, I have a small project that I use to manage remote state you can see here: https://github.com/tomarv2/tfremote

Comment: This is handled fairly completely by a project I put together. https://github.com/getstrake/aws-pricing-sheets-addon

Answer (score 126):

To set this up using terraform remote state, I usually have a separate folder called `remote-state` within my dev and prod terraform folder.

The following `main.tf` file will set up your remote state for what you posted:

```hcl
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state" {
  bucket = "tfstate"
     
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "terraform_state" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state.id

    versioning_configuration {
      status = "Enabled"
    }
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform_state_lock" {
  name           = "app-state"
  read_capacity  = 1
  write_capacity = 1
  hash_key       = "LockID"

  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

Then get into this folder using `cd remote-state`, and run `terraform init && terraform apply` - this should only need to be run once. You might add something to bucket and dynamodb table name to separate your different environments.

Comment: Brilliant answer. FWIW anyone reading "Terraform Up and Running" and stuck in chapter 3 backends (which is using an older version of terreform) this is the solution.

Comment: I assume you're using the `terraform_state_lock` table as a mutex for writing the state, but what reads/writes from it? Does terraform do something behind the scenes there? What happens if you exclude the aws_dynamodb_table resource?

Comment: Ah -- I figured it out. It's because the built-in s3 backend supports locking via a dynamodb table using the dynamodb_table param: https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html#dynamodb_table

Comment: What do you mean by "remote-state folder"?

Comment: @drozzy - not the author, but "remote state folder" in last para means the folder that contains this `.tf` file, which should be a sub-folder in your repo, say `remote-state`.  So you will need to do `cd remote-state` before those two Terraform commands.  I will suggest an edit to clarify.

Comment: just to be sure: so you have 2 folder dev/remote-state and  prod/remote-state , which point to 2 buckets s3  "dev-tfstate-bucket" and "prod-tfstate-bucket" respectively ?

Comment: I am still not able to understand the answer completely.. When we `cd remote-state` and run `terraform apply` - terraform.state for this base infra is still locally saved (with no backend configured), right ? How  does this solve the chicken/egg problem ? Does this state file also come under purview of terraform management now ?

Comment: @akskap it does not COMPLETELY solve the chicken and egg problem, but the state complexity of creating one bucket to bootstrap the rest of the system is minimal. The state can be easily imported if necessary, so I think it is easy to ignore this issue in order to implement this trivial solution. **WARNING**: since the projects are now split-brained, the bucket names must match or you might run into misleading access denied errors (trying to list resources in other peoples buckets).

Comment: @akskap There's always going to be a chicken-egg problem, but the solution with this answer is that you isolate that chicken-egg problem to a very small, likely unchanging terraform state for the S3 bucket. This removes the chicken-egg problem for your potentially large, always changing state of your total infrastructure.

Comment: errors out ` Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
`  with  `Can't configure a value for "versioning": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.`

Comment: Is there a uniform way to parameterize the bucket name and share that with the backend config? I'm able to parameterize with `bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"`, but I cannot share this with a `tfvars` file used to partially configure the `backend` block in my primary terraform project.

Answer (score 27):

Building on the great contribution from Austin Davis, here is a variation that I use which includes a requirement for data encryption:

```hcl
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state" {
  bucket = "tfstate"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "terraform_state" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}


resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform_state_lock" {
  name           = "app-state"
  read_capacity  = 1
  write_capacity = 1
  hash_key       = "LockID"

  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "terraform_state" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state.id}"
  policy =<<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "RequireEncryption",
   "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RequireEncryptedTransport",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state.bucket}/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "RequireEncryptedStorage",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state.bucket}/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: this errors out `│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute`  see open ticket https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23106

Comment: `versioning` argument for `aws_s3_bucket` is deprecated.

Answer (score 18):

As you've discovered, you can't use terraform to build the components terraform needs in the first place.

While I understand the inclination to have terraform "track everything", it is very difficult, and more headache than it's worth.

I generally handle this situation by creating a simple bootstrap shell script. It creates things like:

1. The s3 bucket for state storage
2. Adds versioning to said bucket
3. a terraform IAM user and group with certain policies I'll need for terraform builds

While you should only need to run this once (technically), I find that when I'm developing a new system, I spin up and tear things down repeatedly.  So having those steps in one script makes that a lot simpler.

I generally build the script to be idempotent. This way, you can run it multiple times without concern that you're creating duplicate buckets, users, etc

Comment: Actually, you can use Terraform to build the remote state components (S3 bucket and DynamoDB table) - just use a separate sub-folder for building these, which has its own (local) Terraform state file.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48362341/992887).

Answer (score 15):

I created a terraform module with a few bootstrap commands/instructions to solve this:

https://github.com/samstav/terraform-aws-backend

There are detailed instructions in the README, but the gist is:

```hcl
# conf.tf

module "backend" {
  source         = "github.com/samstav/terraform-aws-backend"
  backend_bucket = "terraform-state-bucket"
}
```

Then, in your shell (make sure you haven't written your `terraform {}` block yet):

```bash
terraform get -update
terraform init -backend=false
terraform plan -out=backend.plan -target=module.backend
terraform apply backend.plan
```

Now write your `terraform {}` block:

```hcl
# conf.tf

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "terraform-state-bucket"
    key            = "states/terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-lock"
  }
}
```

And then you can re-init:

```bash
terraform init -reconfigure
```

Answer (score 9):

Setting up a Terraform backend leveraging an AWS s3 bucket is relatively easy.

First, create a bucket in the region of your choice (eu-west-1 for the example), named **terraform-backend-store** (remember to choose a unique name.)

To do so, open your terminal and run the following command, assuming that you have properly set up the AWS CLI (otherwise, follow the instructions at the [official documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)):

```sh
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket terraform-backend-store \
    --region eu-west-1 \
    --create-bucket-configuration \
    LocationConstraint=eu-west-1
# Output:
{
    "Location": "http://terraform-backend-store.s3.amazonaws.com/"
}
```

The command should be self-explanatory; to learn more check the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html).

Once the bucket is in place, it needs a proper configuration for security and reliability.
For a bucket that holds the Terraform state, it’s common-sense enabling the **server-side encryption**. Keeping it simple, try first **AES256** method (although I recommend to use [KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/) and implement a proper key rotation):

```sh
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption \
    --bucket terraform-backend-store \
    --server-side-encryption-configuration={\"Rules\":[{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\":{\"SSEAlgorithm\":\"AES256\"}}]}
# Output: expect none when the command is executed successfully
```

Next, it’s crucial restricting the access to the bucket; create an unprivileged IAM user as follows:

```sh
aws iam create-user --user-name terraform-deployer
# Output:
{
    "User": {
        "UserName": "terraform-deployer",
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2019-01-27T03:20:41.270Z",
        "UserId": "AIDAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/terraform-deployer"
    }
}
```

Take note of the Arn from the command’s output (it looks like: “Arn”: “arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/terraform-deployer”).

To correctly interact with the s3 service and DynamoDB at a later stage to implement the locking, our IAM user must hold a sufficient set of permissions. 
It is recommended to have severe restrictions in place for production environments, though, for the sake of simplicity, start assigning **AmazonS3FullAccess** and **AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess**:

```sh
aws iam attach-user-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess --user-name terraform-deployer
# Output: expect none when the command execution is successful

aws iam attach-user-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess --user-name terraform-deployer
# Output: expect none when the command execution is successful
```

The freshly created IAM user must be enabled to execute the required actions against your s3 bucket. You can do this by creating and applying the right policy, as follows:

```sh
cat <<-EOF >> policy.json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/terraform-deployer"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::terraform-remote-store"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

This basic policy file grants the principal with arn “arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/terraform-deployer”, to execute all the available actions (“Action”: “s3:*") against the bucket with arn “arn:aws:s3:::terraform-remote-store”.
Again, in production is desired to force way stricter policies. For reference, have a look at the [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html).

Back to the terminal and run the command as shown below, to enforce the policy in your bucket:

```sh
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket terraform-remote-store --policy file://policy.json
# Output: none
```

As the last step, enable the bucket’s versioning:

```sh
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket terraform-remote-store --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled
```

It allows saving different versions of the infrastructure’s state and rollback easily to a previous stage without struggling.

The AWS s3 bucket is ready, time to integrate it with Terraform. Listed below, is the minimal configuration required to set up this remote backend:

```
# terraform.tf

provider "aws" {
  region                  = "${var.aws_region}"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "default"
}

terraform {  
    backend "s3" {
        bucket  = "terraform-remote-store"
        encrypt = true
        key     = "terraform.tfstate"    
        region  = "eu-west-1"  
    }
}

# the rest of your configuration and resources to deploy
```

Once in place, terraform must be initialized (again).
`terraform init`
The remote backend is ready for a ride, test it.

**What about locking?**
Storing the state remotely brings a pitfall, especially when working in scenarios where several tasks, jobs, and team members have access to it. Under these circumstances, the risk of multiple concurrent attempts to make changes to the state is high. Here comes to help the lock, a feature that prevents opening the state file while already in use.

You can implement the lock creating an **AWS DynamoDB Table**, used by terraform to set and unset the locks.
Provision the resource using terraform itself:

```
# create-dynamodb-lock-table.tf
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "dynamodb-terraform-state-lock" {
  name           = "terraform-state-lock-dynamo"
  hash_key       = "LockID"
  read_capacity  = 20
  write_capacity = 20
attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }
tags {
    Name = "DynamoDB Terraform State Lock Table"
  }
}
```

and deploy it as shown:
`terraform plan -out "planfile" && terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve "planfile"`

Once the command execution is completed, the locking mechanism must be added to your backend configuration as follow:

```
# terraform.tf

provider "aws" {
  region                  = "${var.aws_region}"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "default"
}

terraform {  
    backend "s3" {
        bucket         = "terraform-remote-store"
        encrypt        = true
        key            = "terraform.tfstate"    
        region         = "eu-west-1"
        dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-lock-dynamo"
    }
}

# the rest of your configuration and resources to deploy
```

All done. Remember to run again `terraform init` and enjoy your remote backend.

Comment: I've run into a problem while following this process. I cannot create the dynamo db using terraform if I want to frequently destroy other resources during development. Any suggestions to deal with that issue, or should I just use the CLI?

Comment: @utkarsh867 just split the setup of S3 and Dynamo in an isolated project... That way, you can deal with your other resources during development... I personally created a Docker image to setup S3 (shell and terraform itself)...

Comment: Hi, it seems that you mistyped bucket name when you were showing the way to create policies.

Answer (score 8):

What I usually do is start without remote backend for creating initial infrastructure as you said , S3 , IAM roles and other essential stuff. Once I have that I just add backend configuration and run terraform init to migrate to S3.

It's not the best case but in most cases I don't rebuild my entire environment everyday so this semi automated approach is good enough.
I also separate next "layers" (VPC, Subnets, IGW, NAT ,etc) of infrastructure to different states.

Answer (score 5):

What I have been doing to address this is that, You can comment out the "backend" block for the initial run, and do a selected terraform apply on only the state bucket and any related resources(like bucket policies).

```
#  backend "s3" {
#    bucket         = "foo-bar-state-bucket"
#    key            = "core-terraform.tfstate"
#    region         = "eu-west-1"
#  }
#}
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-1"
    profile = "terraform-iam-user"
    shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  }
```

```
terraform apply --target aws_s3_bucket.foobar-terraform --target aws_s3_bucket_policy.foobar-terraform
```

This will provision your s3 state bucket, and will store .tfstate file locally in your working directory.

Later, Uncomment the "backend" block and reconfigure the backend  `terraform init --reconfigure`
, which will prompt you to copy your locally present .tfstate file, (*tracking state of your backend s3 bucket*) to the remote backend which is now available to be used by terraform for any subsequent runs.

[Prompt for copying exisitng state to remote backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydJFM.png)

Comment: Agree, this is a preety simple and useful way for the initial setup.

Comment: how does this work if you're using CICD to deploy for you?

Answer (score 3):

There are some great answers here & I'd like to offer an alternative to managing your back end state;

1. Set up a Terraform Cloud Account (it's free for up to 5 users).
2. Create a workspace for your organization (Version control workflow is typical)
3. Select your VCS such as github or bitbucket (where you store your terraform plans and modules)
4. Terraform Cloud will give you the instructions needed for your new OAuth Connection
5. Once that's setup you'll have the option to set up an SSH keypair which is typically not needed & you can click the Skip & Finish button

Once your terraform cloud account is set up & connected to your VCS repos where you store your terraform plans & modules...
Add your terraform module repos in terraform cloud, by clicking on the Registry tab. You will need to ensure that your terraform modules are versioned / tagged & follow proper naming convention. If you have a terraform module that creates a load balancer in AWS, you would name the terraform module repository (in github for example), like this: terraform-aws-loadbalancer. As long as it starts with terraform-aws- you're good. Then you add a version tag to it such as 1.0.0

So let's say you create a terraform plan that points to that load balancer module, this is how you point your backend config to terraform cloud & to the load balancer module:

backend-state.tf contents:

```
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "YOUR-TERRAFORM-CLOUD-ORG"
    workspaces {
    # name = ""   ## For single workspace jobs
    # prefix = "" ## for multiple workspaces
    # you can use name instead of prefix
    prefix = "terraform-plan-name-"
    }
  }
}
```

terraform plan main.tf contents;

```
module "aws_alb" {
  source  = "app.terraform.io/YOUR-TERRAFORM-CLOUD-ORG/loadbalancer/aws"
  version = "1.0.0"
  
  name = "load-balancer-test"
  security_groups = [module.aws_sg.id]
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  internal = false
  subnets = [data.aws_subnet.public.id]
  idle_timeout = 1200
  # access_logs_enabled = true
  # access_logs_s3bucket = "BUCKET-NAME"
  tags = local.tags
}
```

Locally from your terminal (using Mac OSX as an example);

```
terraform init
# if you're using name instead of prefix in your backend set 
# up, no need to run terraform workspace cmd
terraform workspace new test
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

You'll see the apply happening in terraform cloud under your workspaces with this name: terraform-plan-name-test
"test" is appended to your workspace prefix name which is defined in your backend-state.tf above. You end up with a GUI / Console full of your terraform plans within your workspace, the same way you can see your Cloudformation Stacks in AWS. I find devops that are used to Cloudformation and transitioning to Terraform, like this set up.

One advantage is, within Terraform Cloud you can easily set it up so that a plan (stack build) is triggered with a git commit or merge to the master branch.

1 reference:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/remote.html#basic-configuration

Answer (score 3):

I would Highly recommend using [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) to keep your Terraform code manageable and *DRY* (the *Don't repeat yourself* principle).

Terragrunt has many capabilities - for your specific case I would suggest following the [Keep your remote state configuration DRY](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry/#keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry) section.

I'll add a short and simplified summary below.

---

#### Problems with managing remote state with Terraform

Let's say you have the following Terraform infrastructure:

```
├── backend-app
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── other_resources.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── frontend-app
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── other_resources.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── mysql
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── other_resources.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── mongo
    ├── main.tf
    └── other_resources.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

Each app is a terraform module that you'll want to store its Terraform state in a remote backend.

Without Terragrunt you'll have to write the `backend` configuration block for each application in order to save the current state in a [remote state storage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/remote.html):

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "my-terraform-state"
    key            = "frontend-app/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "my-lock-table"
  }
}
```

**Managing a few modules** like in the above example **its not a burden** to add this file for each one of them -  **but it won't last for real world scenarious**.

Wouldn't it be better if we could do **some kind of inheritance** (like in Object oriented programming)?

This is made easy with Terragrunt.

---

#### Terragrunt to the rescue

Back to the modules structure.
With Terragrunt we just need add add a root `terragrunt.hcl` with all the configurations and for each module you add a child terragrunt.hcl which contains only on statement:

```
├── terragrunt.hcl       #<---- Root
├── backend-app
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── other_resources.tf
│   └── variables.tf
│   └── terragrunt.hcl   #<---- Child
├── frontend-app
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── other_resources.tf
│   └── variables.tf
│   └── terragrunt.hcl   #<---- Child
├── mysql
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── other_resources.tf
│   └── variables.tf
│   └── terragrunt.hcl   #<---- Child
└── mongo
    ├── main.tf
    └── other_resources.tf
    └── variables.tf
    └── terragrunt.hcl.  #<---- Child
```

The root `terragrunt.hcl` will keep your remote state configuration and the children will only have the following statement:

```
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

This `include` block tells Terragrunt to use the exact same Terragrunt configuration from the root `terragrunt.hcl` file specified via the path parameter.

The next time you run terragrunt, it will automatically configure all the settings in the `remote_state.config` block, if they aren’t configured already, by calling `terraform init`.

The `backend.tf` file will be created automatically for you.

---

#### Summary

You can have hundreds of modules with nested hierarchy (for example divided into regions,tenants, applications etc') and still be able to maintain only one configuration of the remote state.

Answer (score 3):

Managing terraform state bucket with terraform is kind of chicken and egg problem. One of the way we can address is:

Create terraform state bucket with terraform with local backend and then migrate the state to newly create state bucket.

It can be a bit tricky if you are trying to achieve this with a CI/CD pipeline and trying to make the job idempotent in nature.

Modularise backend configuration in a separate file.

terraform.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.3.6"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.48.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
}
```

main.tf

```
module "remote_state" {
  # you can write your own module or use any community module which 
  # creates a S3 bucket and dynamoDB table (ideally with replication and versioning)
  source                         = "../modules/module-for-s3-bucket-and-ddtable"
  bucket_name                    = "terraform-state-bucket-name"
  dynamodb_table_name            = "terraform-state-lock"

}
```

backend.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "terraform-state-bucket-name"
    key            = "state.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-lock"
  }
}
```

With following steps we can manage and create state S3 bucket in the same state.

```
function configure_state() {

  # Disable S3 bucket backend
  mv backend.tf backend.tf.backup
  # Since S3 config is not present terraform local state will be initialized
  # Or copied from s3 bucket if it already existed
  terraform init -migrate-state -auto-approve
  # Terraform apply will create the S3 bucket backend and save the state in local state
  terraform apply -target module.remote_state
 # It will re-enable S3 backend configuration for storing state
  mv backend.tf.backup backend.tf
  #It will migrate the state from local to S3 bucket
  terraform init -migrate-state -auto-approve
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I have overcome this issue is by creating the project remote state in the first init plan apply cycle and   initializing the remote state in the second init plan apply cycle.

```
# first init plan apply cycle 
# Configure the AWS Provider
# https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_remote_state" {
  bucket = "terraform-remote-state"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "terraform-remote-state"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

# add this sniped and execute the 
# the second init plan apply cycle
# https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-remote-state"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a version issue here within terraform, for me it is working for the mentioned version. also, it is good to have the terraform state on the bucket.

```
terraform {
    required_version = "~> 0.12.12"
    backend "gcs" {
        bucket = "bbucket-name"
        prefix = "terraform/state"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a word of caution, I would not create a terraform statefile with terraform in case someone inadvertently deletes it. So use scripts like aws-cli or boto3 which do not maintain state and keep those scripts limited to a variable for s3 bucket name. You will not really change the script for terraform state bucket in the long run except for creating additional folders inside the bucket which can be done outside terraform in the resource level.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers provided are very good.  I just want to emphasize the "key" attribute.  When you get into advanced applications of Terraform, you will eventually need to reference these S3 keys in order to pull remote state into a current project, or to leverage 'terraform move'.

It really helps to use intelligent key names when you plan your "terraform" stanza to define your backend.

I recommend the following as a base key name:
account_name/{development:production}/region/module_name/terraform.tfstate

Revise to fit your needs, but going back and fixing all my key names as I expanded my use of Terraform across many accounts and regions was not fun at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use terraform cloud and configure your backend as follows:

```
terraform {
    backend "remote" {
        hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
        organization = "your-tf-organization-name"
        workspaces {
            name = "your-workspace-name"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are running terraform locally and not on some virtual server and that you want to store terraform state in S3 bucket that doesn't exist. This is how I would approach it,

> Create terraform script, that provisions S3 bucket
>
> Create terraform script that provisions your infrastructure
>
> At the end of your terraform script to provision bucket to be used by second terraform script for storing state files, include code to provision null resource.
>
> In the code block for the null resource using local-exec provisioner run command to go into the directory where your second terraform script exist followed by usual terraform init to initialize the backend then terraform plan, then terraform apply

Answer (score -1):

I've made a [script](https://gist.github.com/orihomie/1ec54a4ee4c1cf6e0c955422010f96ca) according to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59903802/3741692) answer. Keep in mind you'll need to import DynamoDB to your tf state as it is created through aws cli.