# How to set up a remote backend bucket with Terraform before creating the rest of my infrastructure? (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, terraform-provider-gcp

How would I go about initializing Terraform's backend state bucket on GCP first with Gitlab's pipeline, and *then* the rest of my infrastructure? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913041/initial-setup-of-terraform-backend-using-terraform) but not sure what that implies with Gitlab's pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is always a difficult question. My post won't answer your question directly but will give my view about the subject. (too long to be a comment)

It's a bit like asking to manage the server where you have your CI tools with the same CI tools (for exemple: the gitlab server managing itself).

If you use gitlab CI to create your repository, you won't be able to keep the state as you would not have remote state to store it for this specific task. This would mean you would have an inconsistent resource with a tf but no state.

If you want to integrate it with your CI I would recommend using gcloud cli inside your ci, checking if the gcs exists and if not creating it.

If you really want to use terraform, maybe use the free tier of terraform cloud with remote backend only for this specific resource. Like this you have all resources managed by tf, and all with a tfstate.

Comment: I'll take it! I'm so new to this that simply reading 'using gcloud cli inside your ci' really gives me a good sense of direction. No idea how to go about doing this yet, but I now know at least what to Google around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You now have another option, which does not involve GCP, with [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#gitlab-http-terraform-state-backend)

> ### GitLab HTTP Terraform state backend

> Users of Terraform know the pain of setting up their state file (a map of your configuration to real-world resources that also keeps track of additional metadata).
> The process includes starting a new Terraform project and setting up a third party backend to store the state file that is reliable, secure, and outside of your git repo.

> Many users wanted a simpler way to set up their state file storage without involving additional services or setups.

> **Starting with GitLab 13.0, GitLab can be used as an HTTP backend for Terraform, eliminating the need to set up state storage separately for every new project.**

> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_0/terraform-gitlab-backend.png]

> The GitLab HTTP Terraform state backend allows for a seamless experience with minimal configuration, and the ability to store your state files in a location controlled by the GitLab instance.
> They can be accessed using Terraform’s HTTP backend, leveraging GitLab for authentication.
> Users can migrate to the GitLab HTTP Terraform backend easily, while also accessing it from their local terminals.

> The GitLab HTTP Terraform state backend supports:

> - Multiple named state files per project

- Locking
- Object storage
- Encryption at rest

> It is available both for GitLab Self-Managed installations and on GitLab.com.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2673).

---

Furthermore, this provider will be supported for the foreseeable futur, with [GitLab 13.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/09/22/gitlab-13-4-released/#taking-ownership-of-the-gitlab-terraform-provider) (September 2020):

> ### Taking ownership of the GitLab Terraform provider
>
> We’ve recently [received maintainer rights to the GitLab Terraform provider](https://github.com/gitlabhq/terraform-provider-gitlab/issues/376) and plan to [enhance it in upcoming releases](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3525).
> In the past month we’ve merged 21 pull requests and closed 31 issues, including some long outstanding bugs and missing features, like [supporting instance clusters](https://github.com/gitlabhq/terraform-provider-gitlab/pull/367).
>
> You can [read more about the GitLab Terraform provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab/index.html) in the Terraform documentation.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_4/gitlab-terraform-tiny.png -- Taking ownership of the GitLab Terraform provider]
>
> See [Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab/index.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/229833).