# Is there a way to track terraform deployments via grafana using influxdb for example

Tags: terraform, devops, monitoring, grafana, influxdb

I would like to monitor all terraform deployments/infrastructure resource creation via grafana dashboards using datasource as influxdb.

Is there any out of box feature available like the way we have influxdb jenkins plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/influxdb/#documentation and all jenkins job details are published in influxdb and can be visualised via grafana dashboard using influxdb as datasource.
so my question is do we have something like this available for **terraform** which can help to save the terraform execution status in influxdb.

basically for *terraform apply*.

any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you expect to achieve? What would you visualise, `plan`, `apply`?

Comment: May be you can store the `.tfstate` files on the supported backed and later use them to visualize in whatever way you need.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since you're asking to do it with grafana, however terraform cloud is free for 5 users and it does exactly that. I've set it myself & it shows every time the terraform plans are run, their existing & past statuses. I give a more detailed answer here on how to set it up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913041/initial-setup-of-terraform-backend-using-terraform/66108721#66108721

Comment: Actually we want to display it using grafana dashboard only since grafana is central monitoring or central dashboard for tracking deployments across various tools in realtime for our usecase

Comment: @ReddysekharGaduputi actually we are looking for solution which  tracks changes in realtime as they occur rather than running in batch mode(scheduled event related to state file )

Comment: How would you track changes in real time, which metric would you use?