# How to ignore S3 Bucket Already Owned By You error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, gitlab-ci

I am creating an S3 bucket and DynamoDB table to store shared state and provide locking, respectively, using Terraform in a Gitlab CI pipeline.

The bucket and db table exist on subsequent runs, as expected. But the stage fails in my pipeline due to "Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou" error from AWS when I run `terraform apply`.

```
│ Error: Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
│   status code: 409, request id: UIGHUK86587686788, host id: 867876IUIUYasdgadsgdfagfdaghfdgfdsfgsdgfdsgdfgsdq8687GJHKHGJK
│ 
│   with aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state,
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state":
│    5: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: error creating DynamoDB Table: ResourceInUseException: Table already exists: uniquestring-shared-state-locks
│ 
│   with aws_dynamodb_table.terraform_locks,
│   on main.tf line 24, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform_locks":
│   24: resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform_locks" {
```

I could potentially write logic into the pipeline yml script, but I must be missing something - running Terraform to apply any modifications, and doing nothing if there are no modifications, is the whole purpose, no?

At this point, I haven't modified anything yet in either the S3 or DB table yet, all I'm doing is re-running the pipeline. Using Terraform v1.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question and answer, using Terraform to track the Terraform's shared state resources is not a good idea: [Initial setup of terraform backend using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913041/initial-setup-of-terraform-backend-using-terraform)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `terraform import aws_s3_bucket.<your-terraform-s3-resource-name> <s3-bucket-name>` first. This happens when the state file got deleted.