# How to setup terraform state on encrypted s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-remote-state

I have setup an s3 backend for terraform state following this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913041/initial-setup-of-terraform-backend-using-terraform) by Austin Davis. I followed the suggestion by Matt Lavin to add a policy encrypting the bucket.

Unfortunately that bucket policy means that the `terraform state list` now throws the

> Failed to load state: AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403, request id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, host id: XXXX...

I suspect I'm missing either passing or configuring something on the terraform side to encrypt the communication or an additional policy entry to be able to read the encrypted state.

This is the policy added to the tf-state bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "RequireEncryption",
   "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RequireEncryptedTransport",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state.bucket}/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "RequireEncryptedStorage",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.terraform_state.bucket}/*"],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: " policy encrypting the bucket" what is the policy? What kind of encyrption exactly did you use? Custom CMK?

Comment: Added in the policy on the bucket

Answer (score 1):

I would start by removing that bucket policy, and just enable the newer [default bucket encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/default-bucket-encryption.html) setting on the S3 bucket. If you still get access denied after doing that, then the IAM role you are using when you run Terraform is missing some permissions.