# terraform remote state best practice

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-state

I am creating a few terraform modules and inside the modules I also create the resources for storing remote state ( a S3 bucket and dynamodb table)

when I then use the module I launch I write something like this:

```
# terraform {
#   backend "s3" {
#     bucket         = "name"
#     key            = "xxxx.tfstate"
#     region         = "rrrr"
#     encrypt        = true
#     dynamodb_table = "trrrrr"
#   }
# }

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0, < 2.0.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

module "mymodule" {
  source = "./module/mymodule"
  region = "param1"
  prefix = "param2"
  project = "xxxx"
  username = "ddd"
  contact = "myemail"
  table_name = "table-name"
  bucket_name = "uniquebucketname"

}
```

where I leave commented out the part on remote state and I leave terraform to create a local state and create all resources (including the bucket and the DynamoDB table).
After the resources are created
I re-run `terraform init` and I migrate the state to s3.

I wonder if this is a good practice or if there is something better for maintaining the state and also provide isolation.

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting approach. I would create the S3 bucket manually since it's a 1 time create for your state file mgmt. Then I would add a policy to prevent deletion | see here: https://serverfault.com/questions/226700/how-do-i-prevent-deletion-of-s3-buckets | & versioning and/or a bkp.
Beyond this approach there are better practises such as using tools like Terraform Cloud which is free for 5 users. Then in your terraform root module configuration you would put this:

```
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname    = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "YOUR-TERRAFORM-CLOUD-ORG"

    workspaces {
      # name = ""   ## For single workspace jobs
      # prefix = "" ## for multiple workspaces
      name = "YOUR-ROOT-MODULE-WORKSPACE-NAME"
    }
  }
}
```

More details in this similar Q&A: [Initial setup of terraform backend using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913041/initial-setup-of-terraform-backend-using-terraform/66108721#66108721)