# Sharing variables between tfvars file and variable block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'll start with some historical stuff and then get to my main question.

I have a very small terraform project that currently uses local backend. I want to start running `terraform apply` in an Azure Devops Pipeline. To do this, I know I need to switch to an s3 backend.

This introduced a new problem of setting up the infrastructure for the s3 bucket. I didn't want to do this by hand or use clumsy scripts. I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48362341/157971) which explains a good solution using a secondary terraform project. This is the approach I'm using today, except I needed to parameterize the bucket name for s3 since it's global across all accounts. Each developer on my team has their own AWS account, so obviously I cannot hard-code the bucket name otherwise it will clash with other developer environments as well as our production environment.

One small change I made to the above solution is to change the `bucket` to use a variable:

```
# Set up the variable...
variable "bucket_name" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the S3 bucket used for the terraform backend"
}

# Use the variable here...
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
  # Other stuff...
}
```

When I apply, I then pass the bucket name there:

```bash
terraform apply -var bucket_name=mybucket
```

From here, I can now do my `terraform init` in the *first* terraform project now that the backend is set up. When I do the init, I provide a tfvars file with the following:

```
# In a file named prod.tfvars
bucket = mybucket
```

As you can see, `mybucket` is duplicated in two places: First at the CLI when setting up the backend, and secondly in my `tfvars` file.

So here's the main question. How can I change what I'm doing to eliminate the duplication? Ideally, the bucket name should be configured in a single place and both terraform projects should use it.

Comment: Inside tfvars, it should be `bucket_name = mybucket` instead of `bucket = mybucket` .

Comment: @RafafTahsin That won't work. if I rename it to `bucket_name` then it won't fill in the `bucket` property under `backend`.