# Issue with GitHub Actions and Terraform on Merging Pull Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, terraform, github-actions

I'm encountering an issue with my GitHub workflow using Terraform for AWS deployment. While creating a pull request, I don't face any problems. However, upon merging the pull request, Terraform is not detecting existing resources on AWS and proceeds to create them. This error occurs during the execution of the Terraform apply step.

GitHub Actions Error:

```
Error: failed creating IAM Role (lambda-role): EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name lambda-role already exists.
│   status code: 409, request id: a9507d81-5420-48ff-bc5b-cb0b5b67292e
│ 
│   with aws_iam_role.lambda-role,
│   on main.tf line 10, in resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda-role":
│   10: resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda-role" {
```

GitHub Actions File:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write

env:
  TF_LOG: INFO
  AWS_REGION: xxxx

defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
    working-directory: ./terraform
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

        # GitHub OIDC
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/github-actions
          aws-region: xxxx

      - name: Set up Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.6.4

      - name: Terraform Format Check
        id: fmt
        run: |
          terraform fmt -check
          continue-on-error: true

      - name: Terraform Initialization
        id: init
        run: |
          terraform init

      - name: Terraform Validation
        id: validate
        run: |
          terraform validate -no-color

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          terraform plan -no-color
          continue-on-error: true

      - name: Update Pull Request
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          PLAN: "terraform\n${{ steps.plan.outputs.stdout }}"
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            ...

      - name: Terraform Apply
        id: apply
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
        run: |
          terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false
```

I have foundational knowledge in Terraform so I do not know how to debug. I tried following this [tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/automation/github-actions) but I do not know how to customize it to integrate to my code.

Comment: What's in your `main.tf` file (that's the file containing Terraform directives)? Pls include it in your post.

Comment: Have you configured a [backend](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration#using-a-backend-block) for your terraform state? ... sounds like you have no backend and the default is to using the local backend, which stores state as a plain file in the current working directory, the GitHub Actions starts fresh every time so previous local backend would not exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initial setup of terraform backend using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913041/initial-setup-of-terraform-backend-using-terraform)

Comment: Yes, from the tutorials that I've been following, they only run the main.tf once. Other tutorials can run the .tf repetitively when an S3 bucket is involved. Is there a way to put the state file in GitHub without S3? (I hope my question makes sense)